# Compiler could not deduce template argument

Tags: c++, c++20

Compiler (VC2019 with c++20) could not deduce template argument for _t1 and _t2 as following code.  Any ideas to solve the problem ?

Thanks for your helps...

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... arg> requires(sizeof...(arg) == 2) 
struct str {
    std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<arg...>>::type _x;
    std::tuple_element<1, std::tuple<arg...>>::type _y;
};

template <typename _t1, typename _t2> 
void _ChTest(str<_t1, _t2> s) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    int i = 1, j = 2;

    _ChTest({._x = i, ._y = j});

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem is not how to deduce  the `_ChTest` method but how to deduce the `str` struct

Comment: @RoQuOTriX sure, do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Changing `_ChTest( { ._x = i, ._y = j })` to `_ChTest(str<int, int>{i, j})` will fix the issue.

Comment: @MircoDeZorzi that is without deducing

Comment: @VeNToR use a constructor with the arguments in the struct

Comment: Please do not use names starting with an underscore as they are reserved by the C++ implementation and add the headers 'n stuff so that one can copy and compile it, see [mre]

Comment: @MircoDeZorzi, yes sure...  but I don't want to use _ChTest(str<int, int>{i, j})... need to be auto deduce ?  is there any solution etc ?

Comment: Can't you simplify `str` to `template <typename T1, typename T2> struct str { T1 x; T2 y;};`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using a variadic templated class you could add the following line to your code:

```
template <typename... Args> str(Args...) -> str<Args...>;
```

This would allow you to do the following:

```
ChTest(str{.x = i, .y = j});
```

Unfortunately this is as good as it gets.

As other have already mentioned in the comments, you should avoid variable names with leading underscore. Here's your code rewritten in a more idiomatic manner.

```
#include <tuple>

template <typename... Args> requires(sizeof...(Args) == 2) 
struct str {
    std::tuple_element<0, std::tuple<Args...>>::type x;
    std::tuple_element<1, std::tuple<Args...>>::type y;
};

template <typename... Args> str(Args...) -> str<Args...>;

template <typename T, typename U> 
void ChTest(str<T, U> s) {
    // ...
}

int main() {
    int i = 1, j = 2;
    
    ChTest(str{.x = i, .y = j});

    return 0;
}
```

P.S.: You should consider re-writing `struct str` as:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
struct str {
  T x;
  U y;
}
```